# Where is the executable file of Kali Linux on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ranger, displayfusion

I would like to add a shortcut in Windows10 using DisplayFusion to
launch WSL Kali Linux and directly open the file manager [ranger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranger_%28file_manager%29).

[image: DisplayFusionSettings]

**Example:** This works quite well for launching a new firefox tab:

- Function Name: *Launch_Firefox*
- Key Combination: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Application: `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`
- Application Parameters: `-new-tab "https://www.google.com"`

KaliLinux launcher:
[image: DisplayFusionAddFunction]

Unfortunately I cant figure out where the executable for Kali Linux is stored.
I know that the Windows-App-Store storage-location of the WSL is
`C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Packages\KaliLinux.54290C8133FEE_ey8k8hqnwqnmg\`
Neither in this path nor in any subdirectory is an executable to find.
Google only shows me results for where the Linux root directory of the WSL is located:
`C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Packages\KaliLinux.54290C8133FEE_ey8k8hqnwqnmg\LocalState\rootfs`

**Q:** Where ist the executable of the WSL (**W**indows **S**ubsystem for **L**inux) of Kali located?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Find the executable:

```
C:\Users\[USER]>where wsl
C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe
```

**Step 2:** Setting up launcher:

[image]

Thanks to [Ken Y-N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270789/ken-y-n) for the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference)!

---

For interested parties: Have a look on "[How to launch Windows apps from Ranger WSL?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446590/245933)".